# How to count how many times a process has received a signal

Tags: c, signals

Another running process (whose code I can't access to) is going to send to my process a bunch of SIGUSR2 signals and two SIGUSR1 signals, in a random order. The purpose of my program is to calculate how many times it has received the SIGUSR2 signal between receiving the first and second  SIGUSR1 signals.

(The other process will start the sending after receiving a SIGUSR1 signal from my process).

I'm a starter at signal handling, so  if it somehow involves looping it makes it harder for me. I've seen that operating with signals the infinite loop is quite a common thing, but it bites me how to implement it correctly.

```
int counter=0;

void count_up(){
    counter++; 
}

void signal_catcher(){
    signal(SIGUSR2,count_up); 
// I think here should go some sort of loop that makes it keep catching SIGUSR2
// There should be some flag or somtehing too, so that it stops after receiving 
// the second SIGUSR1
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pid_sender = atoi(argv[1]);
    kill(pid_sender,SIGUSR1); //The other process is notified to start
    signal(SIGUSR1,signal_catcher); //The first SIGUSR1 is catched 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that. Let's create `SIGUSR2` handler first, based on your one:

```c
int counter;

void catch_usr2(void) {
    counter++;
}
```

And `SIGUSR1` handler:

```c
int sw;

void catch_usr1(void) {
    if(!sw) {
        signal(SIGUSR2, catch_usr2);
        sw = 1;
    } else {
        signal(SIGUSR2, SIG_DFL);
        /* Side note: If you want to count these only single time, remove line below. */
        sw = 0;
    }
}
```

This one at first signal will set `SIGUSR2` to counter procedure, and set `sw` to 1. Next time `SIGUSR1` is catched, the handler removes itself. And let's register it as `SIGUSR1` handler:

```c
signal(SIGUSR1, catch_usr1);
```

Assuming sequence of `2122212`, this code will leave `counter` equal 3.

Comment: I think I understood both of the signal catchers you described, and I thank you for that, but should the rest of the main function remain like I described it? It puzzles me how a single signal(SIGUSR1, catch_usr1) statement can catch SIGUSR1 multiple times without advancing to the next line of code. Not sure if I explained myself too well. Also not sure if I should add a return at the end of the main.

Comment: That's how handlers work. I advise you to learn event driven programming.